# Messages will not login; just sits and spins

Tags: macos, messages

Whenever I open Messages, enter my credentials, and attempt to login the status indicator spins forever and the application never authenticates me and loads.

I had this issue on Mavericks and still have it on Yosemite. I tried removing the frameworks for Messages/iMessage in OS X and even reinstalled the OS from the recovery partition, but nothing works.

Has anyone else had the same issue and any luck with resolving it? Thanks for your time!

Comment: did you also fix your Permissions in Disk Utility?

Comment: I did do this, but it did not help with my issue.

Comment: could you log in to iTunes first than without logging out start messages.

Comment: I am logged in to iTunes, but Messages still does not work. It continues to spin the status indicator for the login screen.

Comment: so the problem is on your site. Could you look in the Console for any logs there.

Comment: @Buscar웃, I see the following message in the console:
2/25/15 8:07:33.295 PM apsd[51]: Certificate doesn't match host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My logic board was recently replaced in this Macbook and the vendor never serialized the newly installed logic board. I discovered this by going to "About This Mac" and seeing the serial number being reported as "Unknown".

The vendor corrected this actually applying a serial number to the logic board, which required specialized software that they had to boot off of from a DVD.

Once the serial number was applied then Messages worked just fine.